# error handler in C program

Tags: c, error-handling, do-while

I am a C programming starter and trying to get my feet wet with writing a primitive number guessing game here. (it is not a school assignment I guarantee it). But since I have met some troubles while I try to complete the whole function I thought that maybe I need a little bit help. So basically I have done the main guessing part of this program: indicate the user his guessing is too high or too low or it is the right answer. However, if the user enters some invalid value like characters or decimals(they are supposed to just enter an integer from 1-100), my program would just prompt the user the guess is out of range and automatically loop this message until the guessing times are used up. I checked my code through but couldn't figure it out. If anybody can give me a thread I will be much appreciated!
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX_NUMBER 100

int main(void) {
    int randNum;
    srand((int)time(0));
    randNum = rand() % 100 + 1;

    long guessNum;
    char guessStr[80];
    guessNum = atoi(guessStr);
    int count = 0;

    do {
        printf("\nplz enter a guess from integer 1 to 100: %d", randNum);
        scanf("%ld", &guessNum);

        if (guessNum < randNum && guessNum >= 1) {
            printf("your guess is lower than the selected number");
            count++;
            printf("\nyou have %d times left to try", 100 - count);
        }
        if (guessNum > randNum && guessNum <= 100) {
            printf("your guess is higher than the selected number");
            count++;
            printf("\nyou have %d times left to try", 100 - count);
        }
        if (guessNum < 1 || guessNum > 100) {
            printf("your guess is out of the range, plz pick between 1-100");
            count++;
            printf("\nyou have %d times left to try", 100 - count);
        }
        if (guessNum == randNum) {
            printf("congrats you got the right answer");
            count++;
            printf("\nyou used %d times to make the right guess", count);
        }

    } while (count < MAX_NUMBER);
    printf("\nthe guess time is used out!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should check the return value of `scanf` - it'll tell you whether a valid integer was entered or not.

Comment: This is definitely wrong: `guessNum = atoi(guessStr);`

Comment: when the guess is right you should make something lets you quit the loop or the program.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Thanks for the hint! I did not know we can do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `scanf` detects input that doesn't match the conversion specifier (such as seeing a letter where it expects a digit), it will stop scanning at that point and leave that character in the input stream, where it will foul up the next read, and the next read after that.

There are several ways to work around this.

First of all, `scanf` returns the number of successful conversions and assignments; for example, `scanf( "%d", &value );` will return 1 if `scanf` was able to read an integer value from the input stream.  So as a start, we can check against that:

```
if ( scanf( "%d", &guessNum ) == 1 )
{
  // test the value of guessNum
}
else
{
  // input wasn't a valid integer; consume input until we see a newline
  char c;
  while ( ( c = getchar() ) != '\n' )
    ;
}
```

A problem with this is that if you enter something like `12r`, `scanf` will convert and assign the `12` while leaving `r` in the input stream.  Ideally, you'd like to reject the entire input as bad.  You can read the character immediately following the input, like so:

```
char follow;
int itemsRead = scanf( "%d%c", &guessNum, &follow );
if ( itemsRead == 2 && isspace( follow ) )
{
  // test value of guessNum
}
else
{
  // input was not an integer followed by a newline
  while ( getchar() != '\n' )
    ;
}
```

This protects you against cases like `12r`.  However, there are still weaknesses.  Believe it or not, `scanf( "%d" )`  *won't* choke on an input like

```
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
```

even though such a value can't be represented by a native `int` type.  Again, you'd like to be able to reject such bad input outright.

A third approach is to read the input as text, then convert it using something like `atoi`, `strtol`, or `sscanf`.  My preferred approach is to use `strtol`, like so:

```
char input[MAX_INPUT_LEN]; // where MAX_INPUT_LEN is appropriate for a signed
                           // integer value; a 32-bit int can represent up to
                           // 10 decimal digits, plus the sign, plus the
                           // 0 terminator.

if ( fgets( input, sizeof input, stdin ) )
{
  if ( !strchr( input, '\n' ) ) // if newline is not present in the input buffer
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "Input too long!\n" );
    while ( getchar() != '\n' )
      ;
  }
  else
  {
    char *follow; // will point to first non-digit character in input
    int tmp = strtol( input, &follow, 10 ); // convert input string to equivalent
                                            // integer value; 
    if ( !isspace( *follow ) && *follow != 0 )
    {
      fprintf( stderr, "%s is not a valid integer value\n", input );
    }
    else
    {
      guessNum = tmp;
      // test value of guessNum
    }
  }
}
```

You'll want to adapt that for your needs (and ideally hide most of that crap in its own function), but you should get the idea.

Comment: Hi John thanks for the very detailed explanation. Nice hint on those two exceptional cases (overline input and letter-number combined input). I was worried about them but now it gets clear :) 
Your third approach is excellent! That is actually how I expected to do for solving this problem as well however I did not know how to do it properly :) I used to do this in Java and it is easier. 
And the evaluating the value of `scanf` thing is pretty cool, it feels like using a neater way of `boolean` to check the value of `scanner` in Java.

Comment: @user1579701: Be aware, I had a typo in the third example (wasn't dereferencing the `follow` variable correctly).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a loop like this:

```
    for (int readNums = 0; readNums == 0; ) {
        printf("plz enter a guess from integer 1 to 100: %d\n", randNum);
        readNums = scanf("%ld", &guessNum);
    }
```

You can eliminate `guessStr` and all references to it, since you don't actually use it.  Also, the usual C idiom is to put the loop exit condition at the top of the loop.  For your program that means your existing `do ... while()` loop would be turned into this:

```
while(count < MAX_NUMBER)
{ 
/* your code here */
}
```

Finally, at the end of the game you'd want a way to actually quit.  You can do that like this:

```
    /* other guess handling code here... */

    if(guessNum == randNum)
    {
        printf("congrats you got the right answer\n");
        count++;
        printf("you used %d times to make the right guess\n", count);
        break;
    }
}
if (guessNum != randNum)
    printf("the guess time is used out!\n");
```

Note, too, that I've used another C idiom, which is to put the `\n` at the end of strings rather than the beginning.

Comment: Yeah I know that I didn't use `guessStr` in the program. But I was just thinking that maybe I should convert the `guessNum` from integer to char so that it can handle the mis-entering-letter exception. The problem is that I do not know how to convert it properly so I just kinda left it over there :)